# Create report from SQL Table using multiple columns counts

Tags: sql

I need a little help in trying to create a report based on the receiver ID, paper and electronic ids seen in the table. The 'where' clause is that some of the Receiver IDs from the source table identify as paper and some identify as electronic IDs.

Paper ID is 11111, Electronic IDs are 12345 and 67890

Input Data

| Received Date | Receiver ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-10 | 12345 |
| 2022-01-10 | 12345 |
| 2022-01-10 | 11111 |
| 2022-01-11 | 11111 |
| 2022-01-12 | 11111 |
| 2022-01-12 | 12345 |
| 2022-01-12 | 67890 |

Expected Output Data

| Received Date | Electronic | Paper |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-10 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-01-11 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-01-12 | 1 | 2 |

Can someone please advise where I am going wrong? I get an error message when trying to run it my query.

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: What is your query and what is the error message?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please add the relevant tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood,this could help you.

```
select A.[Received Date], SUM(A.Electronic) Electronic, SUM(A.Paper) Paper from
(
select [Received Date]
, case when [Receiver ID]='11111' then 1 else 0 end Paper
, case when [Receiver ID] in ('12345','67890') then 1 else 0 end Electronic
from Prueba) A
group by A.[Received Date]
```